# how to change dateformat into yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using AIR DATEPICKER plugin for one of my page for datetime field.now I able to get the date format on placeholder by default **2022-09-01** . but when I select date from datetime calender it's showing me value like **22 September 2022 00:00 am** . I want to get date value in **2022-09-22 00:00 am** So how can I change dateformat?

Here Is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2 datetimepicker d-inline" id="dfield" name="scheduleField" value=""/>
```

Javascript code:

```
const dateInput = document.getElementById("dfield");
// Using the visitor's timezone
//dateInput.value = formatDate();
dateInput.value = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];

function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, "0");
}

function formatDate(date = new Date()) {
  return [
    date.getFullYear(),
    padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
    padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
  ].join("-");
  // dateInput.value = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

Comment: You're not showing either of the functions being called

Comment: I have call by id for showing current date and time in placeholder area but now i want to this format when I want in when I choose to date from calender

Comment: Head to [documentation](https://air-datepicker.com/docs) and look for `dateFormat`

Comment: You should look into `Intl.DateTimeFormat` - you can use this to correctly translate into any date time based on locale etc...

Comment: I mean ... did you try the docs? https://air-datepicker.com/docs#dateFormat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
function formatDate() {
    var d = new Date(),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

   return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
 
console.log(formatDate());
```